# How to disable Meteor.Collection.get() on Browser console

Tags: node.js, meteor, npm, ecmascript-6

**Scenario:**

I have created an app in Meteor 1.5 and the problem is that when I run `Meteor.Collection.get('CollectionName').find().fetch()` inside chrome/firefox console, I see results.

**Requirement:**

1. `Meteor.Collection.get('CollectionName')` should be disabled on browser console.
2. It must show below error message if we try to access Collection using `get()`

   ```
   Uncaught TypeError: Meteor.Collection.get is not a function
   ```

**Analysis and expert's view**

I got a comment to check if `dburles:mongo-collection-instances` is installed. But it was not in my package either. I am stuck as which package is allowing me to view collection on browser console.

**My Meteor package list:**

```
    meteor-base@1.1.0
    mobile-experience@1.0.4
    mongo@1.1.18
    blaze-html-templates
    reactive-var@1.0.11
    tracker@1.1.3
    standard-minifier-css@1.3.4
    standard-minifier-js@2.1.0
    es5-shim@4.6.15
    ecmascript@0.8.0
    kadira:flow-router
    kadira:blaze-layout
    less@2.7.9
    practicalmeteor:mocha
    johanbrook:publication-collector
    momentjs:moment
    twbs:bootstrap
    ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3
    accounts-password@1.3.6
    aldeed:collection2
    check@1.2.5
    ostrio:loggerfile
    mizzao:user-status
    gwendall:auth-client-callbacks
    meteorhacks:ssr
    bryanmorgan:webshot
    manuelro:blaze-math
    awatson1978:browser-detection
    mrt:flash-messages
    babrahams:transactions
    themeteorchef:bert
    session@1.1.7
    iain:accounting
    alanning:roles
    reywood:publish-composite
    aslagle:reactive-table
    natestrauser:select2
    dynamic-import
    aldeed:autoform
    percolate:synced-cron
    mixmax:smart-disconnect
    pfafman:filesaver
    harrison:papa-parse
    cfs:standard-packages
    cfs:filesystem
    tmeasday:publish-counts
    maazalik:highcharts
    jcbernack:reactive-aggregate
    email
    tsega:bootstrap3-datetimepicker
```

Comment: I believe Meteor.Collection is deprecated. Can you try importing Mongo and calling Mongo.Collection? For example if you're using es6: import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo' ;

Comment: Can you explain a bit, how it is related to the problem?

Comment: If your goal is to avoid someone going into the console and being able to see all the data that has been published to the client, you can't. Remember that the client is *not* trusted. You really want to publish only data that you want the user to see.

Comment: @Michel Floyd : my colleague installed his application online, but after logging in , I cannot access `.get` and `.getAll` on his site whether or not i subscribe to Collection. But in my application I see that whether or not i subscribe to any collection, I am able to fire the method call for  `.get` and `.getAll`

Comment: Are you using imports to avoid creating globals? Even with that you can still break into the code at the right point to access the client-side data. Also you can look at the minified js to find collection and method names.

Comment: As for checking if a package is used in your project, look rather in `.meteor/versions` file, as it will also list the package dependencies.

Comment: @ghybs: Thank you for your suggestion. I do see `dburles:mongo-collection-instances@0.3.5` package in there. Is that the main cause?

Comment: also I think as I am using `babrahams:transactions` , it depends on `dburles:mongo-collection-instances@0.3.5` so i guess, this is the reason?